# How can I select a specific image's url on a webpage using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

So I want to scrape this webpage: https://hvg.hu/gazdasag/20220801_rezsi_uzemanyag_gondozas_szocialis_munkas_szocialis_intezmenyek

And this is the part of the html, that I need:

[image]

And I tried codes like this:

```
$(".article-cover-img").attr("src")
```

And everything similar to that, but I can't get the src value of the image. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(".article-cover-img > img").attr("src");
```

because you are selecting div instead of img element.

i hope it was useful.

Comment: What about the cover photo on this page: https://www.origo.hu/gazdasag/20220801-sor-fogyasztas-alkohol-bevetel-europa.html ?